# Ctrl+Shift L do not work together

Tags: 20.04

This is only happening when I use external keyboard and only for left keys. When I press right `Ctrl+Shift`, I can do per-word select essentially combining `Ctrl`(word jump) and `Shift`(select).

But with left keys it doesn't work. I either jump or select depending which key activated first. They do not combine. It also occurs in other situations and shortcuts where `Ctrl+Shirt` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some glitch with keyboard layout. Rebooting didn't help, but when I added another English layout(UK) both UK and US layout started to work normally. I then removed UK and US still works fine.